# Problem installing font package by hand: not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts

I've installed the `bitstrea` package by hand, but when I try to compile, I get this error:

```
! Font OT1/bvi/m/n/10=bvir7t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
d.
```

The file does exist though. How can I configure this correctly, so that it is found?

## More details

I'm on OSX and installed basictex by hand (using the .pkg file). I want to use the `bdeville` font, which exists in the `bdeville.sty` package. This package exists on CTAN here:

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/psfonts/bitstrea

But is not available as a package to be installed through `tlmgr`:

```
$ sudo tlmgr install bitstrea
tlmgr install: package bitstrea not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

Same result for `psfonts`. I also tried looking for another package that has this font, but nothing:

```
$ tlmgr list bdevinne
tlmgr: cannot find package bdevinne, searching for other matches:

Packages containing `bdevinne' in their title/description:

Packages containing files matching `bdevinne':
```

So I installed it by hand, in this folder: `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/commonstuff`

We can verify that the file exists:

```
$ find ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/commonstuff | grep bvir7t
/Users/rgould/Library/texmf/tex/latex/commonstuff/bitstrea/devinne/tfm/bvir7t.tfm
/Users/rgould/Library/texmf/tex/latex/commonstuff/bitstrea/devinne/vf/bvir7t.vf
```

And that the package can be found:

```
$ kpsewhich bdevinne.sty
/Users/rgould/Library/texmf/tex/latex/commonstuff/bitstrea/devinne/tex/bdevinne.sty
```

`kpsewhich bvir7t.tfm` yields no results

How can I make this `tfm` file visible?

Here's my example document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper, margin=1cm}

\usepackage{bdevinne}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Compilation output:

```
$ latexmk test.tex
Latexmk: applying rule 'latex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/Users/rgould/Library/texmf/tex/latex/commonstuff/bitstrea/devinne/tex/bdevinn
e.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.de
f) (./test.aux)
(/Users/rgould/Library/texmf/tex/latex/commonstuff/bitstrea/devinne/tex/ot1bvi.
fd)
! Font OT1/bvi/m/n/10=bvir7t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
d.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.8 \begin{document}

? *geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
(./test.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

Comment: Try running `initexmf --mkmaps` to update the type1 fonts database (as user and as administrator).

Comment: @Bernard this is texlive not miktex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Is initexmf --mkmaps specific to MiKTeX?

Comment: The tfm and the vf are in the wrong place. The tfm belongs into `texmf/fonts/tfm/bitstrea/devinne/`, the vf into `texmf/fonts/vf/bitstrea/devinne/`. But the package is without the real fonts, it contains only the pdftex support files, so unless you own `bvir8a.pfb` you won't be able to use it.

Comment: @Bernard yes, initexmf is a miktex tool.

Comment: I didn't know that. I've learnt something today! :-))

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer! I figured I was falling into a blackhole here but at least you've shown that there is no point in continuing. I will try and find another solution